# How to check one of two radio button in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I get data from AJAX query in Angular JS. It is information about user.
There are two input radio button in page:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="sex" value="1">
<input type="radio" ng-model="sex" value="2">
```

From AJAX I get field `{'sex' : '1'}`. How I can check input with `value = 1` and set it value to `ng-model`?

Answer (score 5):

Start by assigning a name to your inputs, to make them mutually exclusive:

```
<input type="radio" name="sex" ng-model="sex" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="sex" ng-model="sex" value="2">
```

Now, `ng-model="sex"` means that the inputs are populated based on the value of the `sex` property of the scope. So all you need to check the first input, from your controller, is

```
$scope.sex = '1';
```

Comment: The same with input fields?

Answer (score 1):

You can set that in your controller with your `$scope`.

```
<input type="radio" name="sex" ng-model="sex" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="sex" ng-model="sex" value="2">

$scope.sex = '1';
```

then you have set your variable for ng-model and you can use it.